# retaining the relative position of objects while resizing in windows form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Basic in Visual Studio 10 .I have a windows form and I have to display a world map(a jpeg displayed in picturebox ) with radio buttons over each of the country . The problem is while resizing the window the radio buttons get dislocated. One way to fix this is calculating the ratio of

`Scree.width/(initial x-coordinate of radio box)`

and similarly

`Screen.height/(initial y-coordinate of radio box)`

and using this to generate the new x and y coordinates after resizing but as the number of countries are too large this is very tedious and for smaller countries the difference in the initial coordinates is not much and due to precision loss in higher resolution the radio box are overlapping. Is there a workaround for this.  Also the method described isn't working after adding zoom as the portion of image displayed on screen changes and as a followup I would like to ask how can I add sliding functionality to image ( like after clicking the mousedown and moving the pointer should move the image keeping the radio boxes over the respective countries, Is using scroll bars better for this purpose? )

Comment: Make the picture box large, undock it and set the form's AutoScroll property to True.

Comment: @HansPassant not woking

Comment: Please post your form's screenshot. Chances are you need to be using Anchoring, Docking, layout controls, or a combination thereof.

Comment: @Neolisk problem has been solved.

Comment: Good. You can mark below answer as accepted & upvote it. If it did not help you at all, feel free to post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: @Neolisk I followed Bjorn's advice but I changed image layout to stretch

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `PictureBox` with a `Panel`.

With the **PANEL** and your **IMAGE** set:

- *PANEL*.BackgroundImage = *IMAGE*
- *PANEL*.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.None
- *PANEL*.AutoScroll = True
- *PANEL*.AutoScrollMinSize = *IMAGE*.Size

At last, add all `RadioButtons` to the *PANEL*.